# concardation of chart in kendoui mvc

Tags: kendo-ui-mvc

I am using two chart in two different place and both the chart shown sam data and using different controller and model.

here is the code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<AccountChartModel>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("Sales by Month")

 .Legend(legend => legend
            .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
        )
        .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
            .Background("transparent")
        )
        .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
            seriesDefaults.Line().Style(ChartLineStyle.Smooth)
        )
       .Series(series =>
       {
           series.Line(Model.ValueAxis).Name("Sales");
           //series.Line(new double[] { 18495.68, 5748.87, 30000.99, 15005.78, 48520, 29789.14, 9874 }).Name("Sales");
           //series.Line(new double[] { 4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3 }).Name("Russian Federation");
           //series.Line(new double[] { -0.253, 0.362, -3.519, 1.799, 2.252, 3.343, 0.843, 2.877, -5.416, 5.590 }).Name("Haiti");
       })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Categories(Model.CategoryAxis)
            //.Categories("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul")
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis
            .Numeric()/*.Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}%"))*/
            .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        //.AxisCrossingValue(-10)
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("#= series.name #: #= value # $")
        )

//.HtmlAttributes(new { style="height:600px"})
)
```

but when first chart is open in different page second chart not opening.Can anyone tell me what should i do?

Comment: Please clarify "different page."  Different tab in same browser? Different browser instance on same machine?  Different browser type on same machine?  Across two machines?  Or something else?

Comment: @MarcL. can you tell me how do i use a google map in kendo ui mvc view page

Comment: There appear to be lots of search results around that particular question (focusing on ASP.NET MVC itself). Take a look at those resources and try using them.  If you run into a specific issue, that would make a good candidate for a question here at SO--see [help].  Please don't use comments to ask a new question.